# Simplify the queries in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a return set which is group by Category.

```
Category    Total Transactions
============================== 
A                1070 
B                 106
C                  30
```

and i want to filter it with extra condition, which is each categories some items (lets say we use item_codes) need to be excluded from the total transactions, example:
Category A should exclude two items : 1, 3
Category B should exclude three items : 2, 3, 5
Category C should exclude two items : 4, 5

```
Category    Total Transactions
==============================
A             570 (after removed all transactions which contains items 1 & 3)
B              76 (after removed all transactions which contains items 2, 3 & 5)
C              10 (after removed all transactions which contains items 4 & 5)
```

I try not to avoid using sub-query like :

```
SELECT Category, count(id) as 'Total Transactions' FROM TABLE WHERE Category='A' AND items NOT IN (1,3);
SELECT Category, count(id) as 'Total Transactions' FROM TABLE WHERE Category='B' AND items NOT IN (2,3, 5);
SELECT Category, count(id) as 'Total Transactions' FROM TABLE WHERE Category='C' AND items NOT IN (4, 5);
```

Any other idea?

```
sum(case when Category = 'A' then total_transactions else 0 end) as 'A',
sum(case when Category = 'B' then total_transactions else 0 end) as 'B'
```

... But i am not able to combine " items NOT IN (4, 5)"into the where clause.

Thanks.

Comment: Kindly post the full schema @Jack, where is `items` coming from?

Comment: TL; DR; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks. Will do so next time. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Category, count(id) as 'Total Transactions' 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE (Category='A' AND items NOT IN (1,3)) OR
      (Category='B' AND items NOT IN (2,3, 5)) OR
      (Category='C' AND items NOT IN (4, 5))
GROUP BY Category;
```